# Is it permissible in Islam to say assalamu alaikum to a non Muslim?

Tags: non-muslim

Is it permissible in islam to  say assalamu alaikum to a non Muslim?

Comment: Initiating greeting to a non-muslim is makruh or forbidden in general according to many opinions, see https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/61200

Comment: See also [Salam to non-Muslims](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/27498/13438) and ["As-Salāmu \`Alaykum" for non-Muslims?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1827/as-sal%c4%81mu-alaykum-for-non-muslims)